# Why would a switch connected to a router drop a hardwired connection?

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet-connection

I have a PC connected through the wire to the home network. PC is not connecting to the internet through the hard wire but WiFi works. So the ethernet nic picks up the connection when the adapter is enabled and disabled. However, 30seconds after getting an IP it has connection and then drops the internet connection afterwards but still maintains the internal IP. So it appears to allow one to navigate within the internal network but no outside connection to the internet.

The network adapter driver was reset, the adapter power settings have the "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" checkbox unchecked. We rebooted the routers and switches for a fresh session. BUT the issue still occurs. So I am looking to see possible reasons for router dropping a connection... Also its a Lynksys router connected to an unmanaged switch.

Comment: Did you set the Metric correctly?  This setting should have different values for wired and wireless.  Try connecting with just Ethernet (disable wireless) and see if the connection is stable. It is almost always best just to use one connection.

Comment: I have and same effect. So I have to use wireless access to remotely troubleshoot it.

Comment: Can you update the LAN Network Driver in the computer and upgrade the LinkSys firmware?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I already did the driver but the router firmware update is the being left as a last resort for the moment

Comment: Can you try a different router?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. However,  I suspect there is a compatibility issue that the router is not liking.

Comment: I think the compatibility issue is probably the problem rather than your local workstation

Comment: Yeah. It's weird. The Nic or the router that's what I think it comes down too. Problem is on Wifi it works and ethernet it does not. So it is troubling me about the compatibility guess... cause why accept the device through the wifi wireless interface and not through the NIC.

Comment: The wireless connection through the router is different from the Ethernet connection through the router. Two different subsystems in the router box.

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting is in store here. What is the output of `ipconfig /all`? Can you ping the gateway IP? What is the output of `tracert 8.8.8.8`? What is the output of `route print`. All basic ways to check where and what the problem is.

Comment: Yessir. Appleoddity. Those were all tested. It's getting an ip on ethernet and on wireless. I understand the logic behind wifi and ethernet- with them being separate channels. However, it's still within same network. Both nics, get an from the same dhcp. However, the PC itself is being accepted through WiFi and not through ethernet. Yet ip never drops on ethernet but the internet does. So, I'm wondering "why?"   Why accept the device with all its factors through wifi but not through ethernet.

Comment: Moreover, when I hit the windows network troubleshooter it allows for it to give me internet access through ethernet for about 30sec - more or less, then drops it. For 1 it seems like it likes the device for a second and then drops it for some reason as if there are packet losses.

Comment: I am fairly sure now that the router is incompatible and needs replacing

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm a little late but ended up switching the network nic and it is working now. Wanted to update this thread on the solution.